# como hacer inner join con dataframes python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

hola intento hacer un inner join con la librería pandas pero no tengo mucha experiencia en pandas
los datos que recopilo son de una base de datos de mysql son dos tablas con una llave foránea

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
conexionDB = {
        'host':'localhost',
        'user':'root',
        'password':'',
        'database':'cliente'
}
conexion = mysql.connector.connect(**conexionDB)
cursor = conexion.cursor()
#tabla de empleados
tablaA = "SELECT * FROM empleados"
cursor.execute(tablaA)
tabla1 = cursor.fetchall()
tabla1 = pd.DataFrame(tabla1)
cabezera = ['id','Nombre','idarea']
tabla1.columns = cabezera
tabla1.head()
#print(tabla1)
#tabla de area
tablaB = "SELECT * FROM area"
cursor.execute(tablaB)
tabla2 = cursor.fetchall()
tabla2 =pd.DataFrame(tabla2)
#print(tabla2)
#inner join
```

Comment: ¿Por que no directamente desde SQL?

Comment: me piden en el ejercicio usar la librería pandas

Answer (score 1):

```
tabla1.join(tabla2, how='inner', on='nombre-columna')
```

Aunque el default es `inner`, igual y no necesitas el parámetro. El parámetro `on` puede llevar varios índices.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta una duda donde dice nombre-columna pongo la llave la foranea de la tabla ??

Comment: En principio las dos columnas deberían llamarse igual. Pero cuando haces un `merge`, que es muy parecido a un `join` tienes dos parámetros `left_on=""` y `right_on=`, ahora mismo no recuerdo si el `join` tiene los parámetros. Pero chécate la documentación del `merge`, capaz que te sirve mejor

Answer (score -1):

Una opción seria crear una vista de esas 2 tablas en el MYSQL. y después, mandar a llamar esa vista como una tabla normal en tu código de Python

Comment: esas vistas las debo hacer con dataframes de pandas